# a necessary and sufficient condition that homomorphic image of $R$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity.Find a necessary and sufficient condition that homomorphic image of $R$ is a field

---

I am little bit confused about the question. By a necessary and sufficient condition what did they mean? condition on $R$ or the condition on the homomorphism.
If we can find a polynomial $f(x)$ which is irreducible on $R$ then $R/(f(x))$ is a field

Comment: This problem is confusingly stated. It should be a condition on the homomorphism. What do you mean by $R/f(x)$ when $R$ is an arbitrary commutative ring?

Comment: Are you allowed to talk about properties of the kernel of the homomorphism?

Comment: What if the kernel of the homomorphism is a maximal ideal? Isn't that equivalent to $R/M$ being a field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the "first isomorphism theorem" for rings, a homomorphic image of $R$ via $\phi:R\to S$ is isomorphic to $R/\ker(\phi)$.

Since the ideals of $R/\ker(\phi)$ correspond to ideals of $R$ containing $\ker(\phi)$, the quotient will be a field (=have no nontrivial ideals) if and only if there are no ideals strictly between $\ker(\phi)$ and $R$. By definition, that happens exactly when $\ker(\phi)$ is a maximal ideal of $R$.

Since you included unity in your ring, there exists a maximal ideal $M$, and $R/M$ is a homomorphic image of $R$ that is a field. So, the answer to your question as literally written is "this is true for all (nonzero) rings." However, I'm betting you probably did not express your question as you really meant, and that the above paragraph is along the lines of the answer you need.

---

A comment on your idea for a solution: it looks like you are thinking of the polynomial ring $F[x]$ containing an $F$-irreducible polynomial $p(x)$ and then forming the quotient $F[x]/(p(x))$ to produce a field, which is a homomorphic image of $F[x]$.

What you have written, though, makes it look like you've confused the quotient $R[x]/(f(x))$ with "$R/(f(x))$". Even if you succeeded in finding a polynomial that generates a maximal ideal of $R[x]$, this only yields a maximal ideal of $R[x]$, and not $R$ itself.